# Laravel, VueJS [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: did you register the component correctly?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm not sure what I am missing, everything seems to be set up correctly:

app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');


    import CategoriesDataTable from './components/categories/CategoriesDataTable.vue';

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components : {
            CategoriesDataTable,
        },
    });
```

CategoriesDataTable.vue:

```
<template>
    <section class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead></thead>
        </table>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name : 'CategoriesDataTable',
    data() {
        return {}
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

test.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('title', 'Add Category')

@section('app')
<CategoriesDataTable></CategoriesDataTable>
@endsection
```

Doubled checked the spelling but still get

```
app.js:37926 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <categoriesdatatable> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Comment: Try kebab case, `categories-data-table`, within your template. You don't need to change it elsewhere. Note the error message shows the component name in lower case. That's because the template is being parsed as HTML by the browser before it gets to Vue. See also https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended

Comment: Thanks @skirtle. That worked. let's say in `CategoriesDataTable.vue` I change the `name` like so `name : 'add-category'` and then in `est.blade.php` I update the element like so `<add-category></add-category>`, why would that not work? I guess I don't know how the `name` property is used.

Comment: If you still have `components : { CategoriesDataTable },` when you create the Vue instance then that is the name it will use within that root template. You can read more about the `name` configuration option at https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#name but in practice it is much less important than you might expect.

Comment: Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3):

In your blade template you can try this:

```
<categories-data-table></categories-data-table>
```

Then execute npm run watch.

Comment: When you register component in camelcase you must place in blade like this:

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem , in my case i forget command :
Npm run watch

Comment: You could say that in a comment